# How to get the screen resolution in windows 10 with command prompt or powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, windows-10, windows-command-prompt

I have been trying to run

```
wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription
```

it gives me 1920 x 1080 which is good.  I change the resolution to test it and it still returns the same thing.

Does anybody know why?

I have the first screen set to 1360 x 768

The second screen is set to 1600 x 900

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way in powershell.

```
"Background {0}x{1}" -f [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width,[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height
```

Comment: This line may require issuing Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms before you can use it

Comment: Note, that the returned value may be incorrect if the Windows display scaling is not 100%. To make it more robust the returned values must be multiplied by the scale factor. There are examples on the net how to get the scale factor from PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

As stated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967699/get-screen-resolution-using-wmi-powershell-in-windows-7

```
PS> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
PS> [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens


BitsPerPixel : 32
Bounds       : {X=0,Y=0,Width=1280,Height=800}
DeviceName   : \\.\DISPLAY1
Primary      : True
WorkingArea  : {X=0,Y=0,Width=1280,Height=770}

BitsPerPixel : 32
Bounds       : {X=1280,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1200}
DeviceName   : \\.\DISPLAY2
Primary      : False
WorkingArea  : {X=1280,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1170}
```

Comment: See edit. It doesn't work when you change the resolution

Comment: Is that still the case if you close and reopen PowerShell?

Comment: Note, that the returned value may be incorrect if the Windows display scaling is not 100%. To make it more robust the returned values must be multiplied by the scale factor. There are examples on the net how to get the scale factor from PowerShell.